# How can I add a reaction to a command sent by a user? [Discord.py]

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I'm trying to make it so that when a command is executed with no errors it will react to the command message with `:white_check_mark:` and if there's an error it will react with `:x:`. I've tried to do it with the load command and this is what I've got:

```
@commands.check(is_owner)
async def load(ctx, extension):
    try:
        client.load_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
        print(f"The {extension} Cog has been loaded onto main file.")
        await ctx.add_reaction(":white_check_mark:")

    except:
        await ctx.add_reaction(":x:")
```

It doesn't work. Error command is:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'add_reaction'
```

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error said, `Context` doesn't have the `add_reaction` method. You're supposed to add the reaction to a `Message` instance, you can do that with:

```py
await ctx.message.add_reaction("✅")
```

Also the reaction must be a unicode (if it's a default one), to get it simply `\:emoji:` in discord send and copy the resulting message.